# How to account for all user inputs with a cleaner code?

Tags: python, while-loop, user-input

New to Python and writing a simple text-based game. I am trying to account for both invalid user input and unavailable options. I have created a while loop that is functional - but messy. Any guiding lights for a cleaner way to do this? I have tried using the 'or' option to combine the main while loops and simply change the response(invalid/unavailable) based on the condition, but it wouldn't work at all - not really sure why either. for reference, I am using dictionaries to create the conditions and the user function choose_dir() to return a user input for user_dir.*

```
def change_room():
    choose_dir()
    # FIXME
    while user_dir not in ['N', 'S', 'E', 'W']:
        print("Invalid entry.")
        choose_dir()
    else:
        while rooms[current_room][user_dir] == 'None':
            print("Can't go that way.")
            choose_dir()
            while user_dir not in ['N', 'S', 'E', 'W']:
                print("Invalid entry.")
                choose_dir()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single loop, not all these nested `if` and loops. In your code, if the user chooses a direction that leads to `None` in the last call to `choose_dir()`, it won't detect that.

```
def change_room():
    while True:
        choose_dir()
        if user_dir not in ['N', 'S', 'E', 'W']:
            print("Invalid entry.")
        elif rooms[current_room][user_dir] == 'None':
            print("Can't go that way.")
        else:
            return rooms[current_room][user_dir]
```

BTW, it would be better if `choose_dir()` returned the chosen direction, rather than using the global variable `user_dir`.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was going for

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will help you. It's sort of a "gisty" skeleton of what you are trying to do.

```
house = dict(bathroom=dict(n='kitchen', w='bedroom'), kitchen=dict(s='bathroom'), bedroom=dict(e='bathroom'))

room = 'bathroom'
print('Welcome to the %s.' % room)

#tell the user the directions they can go while asking which direction they want
def choose_dir():
    dirs = ','.join(house[room].keys())
    return input('Choose a direction (%s):' % dirs).lower()
    
    
commands = dict(bathroom= dict(take='nothing to take', look='nothing to see', drop='you made a #2'),
                kitchen = dict(take='you took the giant knife', look='there is a giant knife', drop='you dropped thee giant knife'),
                bedroom = dict(take='nothing to take', look='it\'s a bedroom', drop='you faint from exhaustion'))
    
#this is not great, but it gives me something to show how commands can be implemented after a proper direction   
def do_command():
    while (cmd:=input('What would you like to do? ')):
        if cmd in commands[room].keys():
            print(commands[room][cmd])
        elif cmd == 'go':
            break
        else:
            print('%s is not a valid command' % cmd)
        
        
while (d:=choose_dir()):
    #keep asking this question til they get it right
    if not (room:=house[room].get(d, None)):
        print('Invalid direction.')
        continue
        
    print('Welcome to the %s.' % room)
    do_command()
```

Comment: This doesn't distinguish an invalid direction (not NSEW) from a direction that simply has no connecting room.